# C - popen : How to catch an invalid command?

Tags: c, popen

I am trying to run commands sent through popen, however if it is invalid (example kfjhsfdhj) I would like to send a message and not enter my else statement.

From what I understand, if an invalid command is sent, then NULL is returned from popen (I might be wrong about this!).

I tried the following code but it does not seem to work as I want it to, any ideas?

```
char ans[10000];
FILE* file = popen("blabla", "r");

if(file == NULL){
  printf("The command you wish to execute is invalid.\n");
  //I want this output and the else to not execute
} else {
  char buffer[10000];

  while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != NULL){
    strcat(ans,buffer);
  }

  pclose(file);
  //export data to file
  FILE *result = fopen("results.txt", "a");

  if(result != NULL){
    num+=1;
    fprintf(result, "Query no. %d:\n", num);
    fputs(ans, result);
    fclose(result);
  } else {
    printf("Error with result file!\n);
  }

}
```

When I run it, I get `sh: 1: blabla: not found` and I get `Query no. X` entered in the results file with nothing following it. Another command will append properly to the file.

It works as intended with a valid command.

Comment: Shells return 127 for "command not found". `pclose()` blocks and returns the exit code.

Comment: what do you mean by pclose() blocks? Where is the exit code returned and how can I use it?
I've tried to change my NULL to a variety of 127s with different pointer casts etc, as well as checking if pclose() gives mes 127, no luck.

Comment: What I said is described in the man page for popen, which I guess you should read. What exit code does pclose come back with in your case?

Comment: Yes I've read the man page :)
It states that an error is returned only if the argument is invalid, but not if the command is invalid.
I am new with popen and pclose and cant see to get the return value:

`FILE * file = popen(command1, "r");
 int ret_val = pclose(file);
 printf("%d", ret_val);`

does not print anything.

Comment: You forgot the newline in your printf... try: printf("%d\n", ret_val);... btw on my Ubuntu Linux system, passing a junk command in popen() causes pclose() to return x'7f00' ... i.e. the high-order byte is 127 ... full int = 32512

Comment: THANK YOU @tonyB !!! compairing the return 32512 works for me (:
Is the same value returned on other linux systems? I too run ubuntu but what if I was to use it elsewhere?

Comment: I'd test it for non-zero... because I get a zero return from pclose() if I pass a good command....

Comment: Use `WIFEXITED` and `WIFSIGNALLED` to test whether the exit was due to an exit or a signal.  Use `WEXITSTATUS` to get the exit code if it exited, and `WTERMSIG` to get the signal if it signalled.

Comment: regarding: `printf("The command you wish to execute is invalid.\n");`  error messages should be sent to `stderr` not `stdout`.   When the error originates from a system function, should also send the related text that indicates why the system thinks the function failed.  There is a specific library function to handle all of this:  `perror()`

Comment: in general, when a call to `popen()` fails, call `perror()` then call `exit()`

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll be sure to test out all possibilities. This really helped me!